# Decay probability using quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, radiation

Usually when calculating the alpha decay rate using quantum mechanics one treats the alpha particle and the product nucleus as two fragments bound together inside a potential well. One then slices the potential barrier into thin slices and then caluclates the tunneling probability for the alpha particle through such a barrier and then takes the product of all the probabilities for each barrier... An example of this is given on page 10 of : https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-02-introduction-to-applied-nuclear-physics-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_02S12_lec_ch3.pdf .

My question is : Why dont we cut the potential into potential steps rather than potential barriers. One could then calculate the probabilities of a particle passing all those steps? So basically: why not potential steps rather than barriers?

This is what I mean by steps:

[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_Schrödinger_equation_for_a_step_potential](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation_for_a_step_potential)

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly mean potential steps/potential barriers. You say, you *slice the potential barrier into thin slices*. Isn't it what you mean by steps?

Comment: A potential step is not equal to a potential barrier... The calculation for tunneling is done for a potential barrier with some small width, and then the net probability for tunneling is just a product  of all the probabilities for tunneling through those barriers ($\textbf slices$), as seen on the picture...  But why can't the particle move (tunnel) through the potential in small steps, jumping from one ($\textbf step $) to another, in the sense of the Wikipedia link I included... It's kinda hard to explain what I mean...

Comment: Do you mean - why particle physically doesnt move by small slices inside the barrier? One thing is the calculation method, another is a physical picture. Am I close to what you want to say?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwQrEx841P-jQ1RFd0VZODJUMG8

I apologize for the late reply, I made a sketch of what I mean by steps...

Comment: it is maybe like you want to do kind of  integration, but i am not sure, that several slices is equivalent to Coulomb. The particle after the 1st lsie has some wavefuntion and if you put another slice, the previous wavefunction would not be the same after...

Answer (score 2):

Potential barrier here means the energy V, and the "step" describes the shape of the barrier.